# Having an error with installation of jspdf and jspdf-autotable

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Am not able to install jspdf and autotable its giving me the above error .Help me with this.And am trying this example https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the latest npm release npm@5.4, see [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380).

If you're using npm v5, you can downgrade to npm@5.3:

```
npm i -g npm@5.3
```